# How to set default value of an entry on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a form and its something like this

```
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Form")

name = Label(root, text="Name", width=20,bg = "black", fg="red")
name.place(x=150, y=50)

name = Entry(root, width=20, bg = "black", fg="red")
name.place(x=150, y=100)

print(name.get)
```

and lets say someone leaves the "name" blank i want my code to detect that and print "unknown"
instead of nothing

tip: i dont want the entry to have a text in it with already wrote unknown i want to be able to leave it blank and my print still be able to print unknown.

problem with the float:

```
def submit():
    kilograms = entry_kilo.get()
    kilo_float = float(kilograms)
```

Comment: Have you considered to alter the print? it would be easier and quicker: ```print(name.get if name.get != "" else "Unknown")```

Comment: well that is possible i think but i'm making a template using factor maker that sends output from the form i filled to a word file. the entry values go to a dictionary that says something like this context : {name: 'entry_name'} and that goes to the docx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class I made so that it supports this type of activity.

```
from tkinter import *

class Custom(Entry): #inheriting from the Entry class
    def ret(self):
        if self.get() == '': # if empty then assign
            return 'Unknown'
        else:
            return self.get() # else give the same thing out

root = Tk()
root.title("Form")

name = Label(root, text="Name", width=20,bg = "black", fg="red")
name.place(x=150, y=50)

a = Custom(root, width=20, bg = "black", fg="red") #instantiating using all the same option you did before
a.place(x=150, y=100)

print(a.ret()) #Prints unknown
print(a.ret() == a.get()) #prints false obviously, just a testimony ;)

root.mainloop()
```

Here you have to use `a.ret()`, why? because thats how i defined it inside of the class. You could use `a.get()`, but it will just give you the usual blank string.
And I dont think its possible to overwrite the existing `get()` method other than editing the `__init__.py` file of tkinter, do let me know if i'm wrong.

You can also shorten the class to just a little over multiple lines, like:

```
class Custom(Entry):
    def ret(self):
        return 'Unknown' if self.get() == '' else self.get() #does the same thing as before
```

Keep in mind, you can replace `'Unknown'` with anything you like.

This is not the best of codes, as I have not used classes before. Why use classes? Because its not something thats possible with the default tkinter, i believe. So why not just make a custom class and get this effect ;)

How are you supposed to use this with your project? Just replace all the `Entry(..)` with `Custom(..)`. It supports all the options that a usual `Entry` widget does too.

Make the changes here to fix the error:

```
def click():
    kilograms = a.ret()
    kilo_float = a.ret()
    try:
        kilo_float = float(kilograms)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print(kilo_float)
```

Hope this helps you. Do let me know if you have any doubts or errors.

Cheers

Comment: it worked for normal strings. i tried it with float entries it gave me ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' if you could help me with that i would appreciate it. (and unfortunately i cant upvote because my rep is low)

Comment: like float and integer entries                example: a = Custom(root, width=20, bg = "black", fg="red")         float_a = float(a)

Comment: @StrawpickGaming It should be `float_a = float(a.ret())` but still, it will show same error if the box is empty too

Comment: editted the code. added where i got the error. i want to be able to leave the float entries blank and get "0" for example